How to change Excel default save dialog to use the Windows explorer "browse" option
Whenever I save an "Excel for Microsoft 365" file, the default save dialog only shows the last few folders that were used, so then I have to click "more options". Then the "more options" dialog doesn't show all of the Windows explorer pinned quick access items and is very clunky to navigate (and doesn't support alt+d to quickly paste your save folder path) so I end up scrolling to the bottom of the left-hand save as menu, and then clicking "browse" which finally gets me to a normal Windows explorer save dialog.
Is there a way to have Excel open the save dialog in the Windows explorer "browse" option by default (like most other Windows apps)?  I've tried changing various Excel options but haven't had any luck so far.
